# .htaccess redirect url with query string to other page + query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm encountering a problem with my .htaccess file and with my limited knowledge of PHP I cant seem to figure this one out.

Goal: I want to redirect traffic that goes to my main page but has a query string, to be redirected to a different page with the query string intact. Like so:

```
https://www.mywebpage.com/?wd8RL4T6Q00&17.07&52LJqY-emLU&0
```

to

```
https://www.mywebpage.com/player.html?wd8RL4T6Q00&17.07&52LJqY-emLU&0
```

The user can only see the first and underlying pages like (https://www.mywebpage.com/howto.html) still have to be reachable.

In pseudo code (but somewhat resembling javascript ;) my solution would be something like:

```
if (querystring) {
  redirect to './player.html' + querystring
}
```

What I have tryd:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule player.html  %1
```

But this seemed to redirect all traffic somehow..
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current RegExp just matches everything. That's what the `.*` means. Instead, if you want the query string to have at least 1 character, you can change it to `.+`. I think that solves your current problem.

Then, for the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule .* /player.html [L]
```

Comment: Hey Daan, thanks! That works! Now it selects only the links that have a query string in them. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)

Comment: Great! If it's the solution to your problem, please accept my answer :)

Comment: Well, it is for the first part.. but not for the second part. I guess this line is right now: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)   So it rewrites only the links that have a query string in them. But not this line: RewriteRule player.html  %1   So it still comes up with a 500 error. Do you know what I can do to refer it to the right page with the query string attached?

Comment: I've added to my answer. Is this what you hoped to achieve?

Comment: Hey Daan, thanks for your anwswer again! I'm getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Maybe it picks up on the query string again when redirecting to /player.html?wd8RL4T6Q00&17.07&52LJqY-emLU&0 ? Don't know if the .htaccess file is read again after the redirect. Also the URL visible to the user changes now to: 

mywebpage.com/player.html?wd8RL4T6Q00&17.07&52LJqY-emLU&0. That is not supposed to happen. It should say: 

mywebpage.com/?wd8RL4T6Q00&17.07&52LJqY-emLU&0

Comment: I've amended the rules. The second RewriteCond means it will only trigger for `/`, and not for `/player.html`.

Comment: Awsome! No errors anymore! Only 1 thing left: is it possible to not show the user the player.html part?

Comment: Yes. If you don't use `[R,L]` but just `[L]` in the `RewriteRule` part, it shouldn't redirect the user to `/player.html`, but just handle it using that file.

Comment: By the way, if my answer solved your problem, please accept it :)

Comment: Whoops, forgot to control+f5 :) It completely works now! Thanks so much Daan!